# Sagemaker CPU performance slow

Tags: python, mysql, bigdata, cpu, amazon-sagemaker

I have a question regarding to retriving records of a big data by using Sagemaker. I used pd.read_spl with chunk to read a big data and use for loop to go through all the sub dataframes to generate a bigger dataframe. While I used my own laptop(8cores with 8G Ram) it took 1.4 hours. And then I moved to Sagemaker and used instance (8cores,32G Ram) and it took 6hrs! I thought it should have been faster. The code is the same. I couldn't understand why. The only thing I can see difference is, the CPU performance in my laptop can go up to 70% sometimes while in Sagemaker it is only about 5%. Again, I am not sure why it is the case. I thought Sagemaker should perform much better.

Comment: Never used sagemaker. But perhaps try increasing the chunk size?

Comment: How many kilometers away is the Sagemaker?  TRACERT to Sagemaker to get idea of number of hops.

Comment: Increasing chunk size won't help, tried before. But still thank you for suggesting. Torxed

Comment: It is within the same region. I never tried TRACERT, but will give it a call. Thank you. Wilson

Comment: Can you please post your example code?  Also, what NotebookInstance.InstanceType (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateNotebookInstance.html#sagemaker-CreateNotebookInstance-request-InstanceType ) are you running this on?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am facing same issue. Epochs are terribly slow.